# Expressing want and together

Tags: grammar, nuances

To learn Japanese, I am currently using Duolingo.
One of the sentences it wants me to translate is "Do you want to go to the park with me?"

The answer I am supposed to give is：
いっしょに公園にいきませんか？

I get that いっしょ is meant to represent the "together" part of the sentence.
I also get that ませんか represents the fact that it is more polite to say "don't you want to" instead of "do you want to".

However, nowhere does the sentence really include the want part. Would it be correct to say the following instead:
いっしょに公園に行きたいますか

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right. Duolingo translated it loosely. You could be more direct and ask いっしょに公園に**行きたいですか**

For more information on how to say want, I recommend you read [this.](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/desire)

Comment: I wonder if you could use the rethoric question here as well いっしょに公園に行きたくないですか

Comment: Thanks!　Also, and this is only loosely related, do you know why we put the ni-particle after いっしょ? It's not like issho is a place or a direction or something, right?

Comment: Oh, and also, why is it 行きたいですか and not 行きたいますか?

Comment: ＠Felipe Oliveira I think yes, since if they truly don't, they won't have to disagree with you. Maybe. @Gandalf Smith Try [this.](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1985/why-is-%E4%B8%80%E7%B7%92%E3%81%AB-correct-and-%E4%B8%80%E7%B7%92%E3%81%A7-incorrect) I'm not really sure. Also, いきたい has become an adjective. It works differently compared to English "I want to go."

Comment: @requiredandshown the "tai form" turns the verb into an "i - adjective", therefore it no longer conjugates as a plain verb. Please give some research into the "tai form" there is plenty of materials about that out there ^^

Comment: I think you read my comment wrong. I wasnt sure what makes 一緒に different from adverbs without
 に、 so I linked to a related question on this website.

Comment: @requiredandshown I was meant to tag the op, not you. Sorry